# Android ListView - Slide Subview in from Right?

Tags: android, listview, subview

I have a ListView. When I select an item in the ListView, I would like to have a Subview slide in from the right, the way that it does in many Apps.

I have been searching for tutorials on this topic but am spinning  my wheels. Maybe Android uses a term different than "Subview" ?

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Create a New Class for the SubView
2. Add the Subview class to the Manifest with `<activity android:name=".SubViewClassName" />` inside the `<application>` tag
3. Add this to the main Class ("lv" is the ListView)

   > lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   >           public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent,
   >   View view,int position, long id) {
   >
   > ```
   >        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),SubView.class);
   >
   >            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);  
   >
   >    }
   > ```
   >
   > });

Comment: There is no "subview" in Android, at least not by that name.

Comment: An image of what? I want to click an item on the ListView and then make a new ListView appear, based on which row was selected in the original ListView.

Comment: hey hi, how you solved this problem? please reply..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing is to have your second `ListView` be in a separate `Activity`. If the user has inter-activity animations enabled (and that is the default), then your second `ListView` will slide in from the right.

Comment: You can also override the transition using Activity.overridePendingTransition() if you want to force the user to have slide left/right transitions between activities.

Answer (score 3):

For this to work you will need to use a ViewFlipper

Here is how you would set up your main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/flipper" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <include android:id="@+id/first" layout="@layout/home_screen" />
  <include android:id="@+id/second" layout="@layout/info_screen" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

The xml files for the two views are home_screen and info_screen in this case.  You can name them anything you'd like.

In your code you will need to place this in your onCreate() method:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
```

Additionally you need these methods below your onCreate() method.

```
    private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromRight.setDuration(800);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}
private Animation outToLeftAnimation() 
{
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    outtoLeft.setDuration(800);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
}
private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
    Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromLeft.setDuration(800);
    inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromLeft;
}
private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
    Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    outtoRight.setDuration(800);
    outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoRight;
}
```

And when you're ready simply use

```
flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
flipper.showNext();
```

Comment: Thanks... I will try this and report back.

Comment: No problem.  Any luck with it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but you can use an `overridePendingTransition` in this sub activity ?

In your main activity :

```
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    Intent myIntent= new Intent(this, MySubActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("param1", param1); // some parameters
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

Or whatever code you want. The main thing is in your subactivity (and subview) like in `MySubActivity` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // autogenerated code and your code here
    ...
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
 }
```

Here are the animation files in the `res/anim` folder

enter_from_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

exit_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just small addition to Ryan's response (Using ViewFlipper):

```
public void onShowRight(View v) {
    flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
    flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
    flipper.showNext();         
}

public void onShowLeft(View v) {
    flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
    flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
    flipper.showPrevious();         
}
```